# How can I update to a newer eclipse for c++, without losing my work? What should be the website link for update?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipselink, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to add a URL to windows->preferences->install/update->available software sites.

And then I click on Help->Check for update.

It gives me an error : No updates Found. No repository found at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/3a/eclipse-cpp-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1248.

Can anyone help me with this? What URL should I use. And what is the correct way to upgrade Eclipse so that I dont lose my work.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I am trying to use this URL:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/3a/eclipse-cpp-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1248

Comment: I recommend against posting links that automatically download things...

Comment: Thanks DeiDei . But what should be the link? Can I use the same link?